# Query on accessing array object from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs currently I am learning how to read array objects and display in view.

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-app="myDirective" ng-controller="myController">
<div class="container border_bottom">
    {{welcomeMessage}}<br />
    <label>First Name</label> : {{fullname.firstName}}<br />
    <label>Last Name</label> : {{fullname.LastName}}<br />
    Employee Details <br /> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="emp in employee">
            <div>                    
                <label>Employee ID</label>{{employee.empId}}<br/>
                <label>Employee Name</label>{{employee.empName}}<br/>
                <label>Voter Count</label>{{employee.voteCount}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

AngularJS Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myDirective", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
$scope.welcomeMessage = "Hello ";
$scope.fullname = { firstName: "Mahadevan", LastName: "Sivasubramanian" }

$scope.employee = [
    { empId: 1, empName: "Mahadevan", voteCount: 0 },
    { empId: 2, empName: "john", voteCount: 0 },
    { empId: 3, empName: "Siva", voteCount: 0 }
];
});
```

I am not getting any error. Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: it works fine, what is the issue?

Comment: I am not getting the value of array

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access **`emp`** not **`employee`** inside **`ng-repeat`**

```
<li ng-repeat="emp in employee">
                <div>                    
                    <label>Employee ID</label>{{emp.empId}}<br/>
                    <label>Employee Name</label>{{emp.empName}}<br/>
                    <label>Voter Count</label>{{emp.voteCount}}
                </div>
</li>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myDirective", []);
myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
$scope.welcomeMessage = "Hello ";
$scope.fullname = { firstName: "Mahadevan", LastName: "Sivasubramanian" }
$scope.employee = [
    { empId: 1, empName: "Mahadevan", voteCount: 0 },
    { empId: 2, empName: "john", voteCount: 0 },
    { empId: 3, empName: "Siva", voteCount: 0 }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myDirective" ng-controller="myController">
<div class="container border_bottom">
    {{welcomeMessage}}<br />
    <label>First Name</label> : {{fullname.firstName}}<br />
    <label>Last Name</label> : {{fullname.LastName}}<br />
    Employee Details <br /> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="emp in employee">
            <div>                    
                <label>Employee ID</label>{{emp.empId}}<br/>
                <label>Employee Name</label>{{emp.empName}}<br/>
                <label>Voter Count</label>{{emp.voteCount}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: actually my trainer accessing emp not employee why for them is coming but not for me

Comment: you should access emp only

Answer (score 1):

You should access the current element by `emp` in the model of your ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="emp in employee">
            <div>                    
                <label>Employee ID</label>{{emp.empId}}<br/>
                <label>Employee Name</label>{{emp.empName}}<br/>
                <label>Voter Count</label>{{emp.voteCount}}
            </div>
</li>
```

**ng-repeat simple usage**

```
<div ng-repeat="anElement in anArray">
  {{anElement}}
</div>
```

Comment: I hope SO questions are designed to be answered more than once if one deems that is appropriate.

Comment: It should be - "Yes you are correct, but not the same *words"

Comment: Well if it so, then my mistake. Usually its the answers should not be the same! btw I did not downvote

Comment: Well I never thought you did. But it is easier to find in SO the answers which cite same solution for a problem than different ones.